# How do I print the output of google sheets script back to google sheet?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, url, custom-function

I am trying to use an api for verifying phone numbers and emails for the database I want to create in google sheets. I coded the following on app scripts of sheet.

```
function phone(phno) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://neutrinoapi.net/phone-validate?user-id=USERNAME_HERE&api-key=API_KEY_HERE&number="+phno+"&country-code=IN")

  // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  Logger.log(data["valid"]);
  Logger.log(data["prefix-network"]);
  Logger.log(data["type"]
}
```

The json returns a bunch of things, valid = true\false {If the number is valid}; prefix-network = service_provider; type = mobile\landline etc.

The idea is that if I call = phone(D2) in cell E2 for example, where D2 stores a valid phone number, I want the validity to be shown in E2, which is a boolean of true\false for if the phone number is valid or not. I would also love to show the next 2 columns with prefix-network and type. But they aren't necessarily essential, just desirable.

The API works fine, and I can see the output in the execution logs in App Scripts, and it's correct with a few test data I tried. However, I cannot find any way to display the result back in the sheet in cell E2. The code has to be generic such that if I drag the code for the cell, it should return the output to the subsequent cells.

I hope the question is clear and the code is sufficient to explain it.
Looking forward to the replies.
Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: just return the data in inside a 2d array: `return [ [data["valid"], data["prefix-network"], data["type"]] ]` be ware that if you open the sheet all the data is recalculated. You probably want to paste it as hard values and when you rerun the code, check if you already have checked the phone number.

Comment: This thing works. It returns 3 values in 3 cells as expected. Thanks! How do I prevent it from recalculating it every time? I don't want to exceed my daily free limit and if the list goes above 50, then it'll just calculate the first 50 and not the newer ones. Do you know how I can fix that? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if this is an ok truck or not. but I found a hack. After the API returns and the data is stored, I just copy it and paste it as plain text. That way, the data is not calculated real time and that fits the purpose here..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
function phone(phno) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://neutrinoapi.net/phone-validate?user-id=USERNAME_HERE&api-key=API_KEY_HERE&number="+phno+"&country-code=IN")

  // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  Logger.log(data["valid"]);
  Logger.log(data["prefix-network"]);
  Logger.log(data["type"]
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(1,1,1,3).setValues([[data["valid"],data["prefix-network"],data["type"]]]);
}
```

Comment: It isn't working for some reason. It shows, Exception: You do not have permission to call setValues (line 13). which is the last line of the code. I have allowed all authorizations and it fetches data correctly though. Why can't it push it?

Comment: If you are using this function as a `Custom Function` in a cell, this is expected behavior. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=en#return_values). Otherwise, if you run this function as a standalone method and still receive this exception, make sure the user executing this code has enough Edit permissions over the Spreadsheet.

Comment: Sorry about that I always forget about custom functions because I never use cell functions.